# ¿Como puedo modificar un registro que tengo en una tabla en asp.net mvc por un dato que me regresa un evento de javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, c#, asp.net-mvc

Agradezco quien pueda ayudarme! tengo mi código en asp.net MVC que llena una tabla, al cambiar una fecha en una celda que tengo con un datepicker me ejecuta un evento de javaScript para mostrar un valor que esta llegando a un ajax como data, pero antes de que se ejecute el evento javaScript intento que inicialmente me muestre el valor que ya existe en una tabla SQL Server con la que lleno inicialmente la tabla y que cuando se ejecute el evento de javaScript se vea el nuevo valor calculado en la función pero como lo estoy intentando muestra el que existe en la BD y cuando ejecuto el evento me aparecen los dos datos.
este es el código:
**Esta es la vista**

```
@model IEnumerable<ResumenModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Resultado de dias";
    var idFecha = 0;
    var index = 0;
}

@*===========VISTA PARA REALIZAR LA CONSULTA DE EMISION============*@

<div class="container mt-3">
    @*=========== TITULO DE LA BUSQUEDA ============*@
    <blockquote class="blockquote text-center">
        <h2>FREE DAYS / DEMURRAGE</h2>
        <p>search result:</p>
    </blockquote>
    @*=========== TABLA DE RESULTADOS DE LA BUSQUEDA ============*@
    <table class="table" id="tablaLiquidacion">
        @*=========== CABECERA DE LA TABLA ============*@
        <thead class="table-success">
            <tr>
                <th>BL</th>
                <th>Container</th>
                <th>Free days</th>
                <th>
                    <div>Last free day</div>
                    <div><small>(Última fecha libre)</small></div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div>Return date</div>
                    <div><small>(Fecha devolución)</small></div>
                </th>
                <th>Chargeable days</th>
                <th>Chargeable amount</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @*=========== CUERPO DE LA TABLA ============*@
        <tbody id="myTable">
            @foreach (var resumen2 in Model)
            {
                index = index + 1;
                idFecha = index;
                <tr>
                    
                    <td>
                        <output id="idBl_@idFecha">
                            @resumen2.Id
                        </output>
                    </td>
                    
                    <td>
                        <output id="idCntr_@idFecha">
                            @resumen2.Numero
                        </output>
                    </td>
                    
                    <td>@resumen2.DiasLibres </td>

                    
                    <td>
                        <output id="idLast_@idFecha">
                            @(resumen2.FechaLibre.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                        </output>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <p class="w-50">
                            @{
                                DateTime FechaActual = DateTime.Now;
                                string Fechacambio = FechaActual.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                                <input class="btn-outline-grey" type="date" id="idFecha_@idFecha" value="@Fechacambio" name="fechaCambio" oninput="calculardiasDiscount(@idFecha)">
                            }
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    
                    <td>
                        <output id="chargeableDays_@idFecha" />
                    </td>
                    
                    <td>
                        @resumen2.calculoSP
                        <output id="chargeableAmount_@idFecha" />
                    </td>                    
                    
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
<script>
    let total=0;

    function calculardiasDiscount(Id) {
        let vLastFreeDay = new Date(document.getElementById('idLast_'+Id).value);
        let vFechaCambio = new Date(document.getElementById('idFecha_'+Id).value);
        var diff = vFechaCambio.getTime() - vLastFreeDay.getTime();
        document.getElementById("chargeableDays_"+Id).value = Math.round(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

        /////////////////////   creado   /////////////////////////////

        let VchargeableDays = document.getElementById("chargeableDays_"+Id).value = Math.round(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));


        /////////////       VARIABLES PARA EL STORE PROCEDURE    ////////////////

        let vCHB_Bl = new String(document.getElementById('idBl_'+Id).value);
        let vCHE_Equipment_Number = new String(document.getElementById('idCntr_'+Id).value);
        console.log(vFechaCambio);
        console.log(vflexCheckDefault);

        ////////////////////////  CAMBIAR FECHA     ////////////////

        var date = vFechaCambio;
        const formatDate = (date)=>{
        let formatted_date = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear()
        return formatted_date;
        }
        console.log(formatDate(date));

        /////////////////  ajax  Para CalcularDemoras  /////////////

        $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("LlamdoSp","Home")',
        data: {Fecha:formatDate(date),Cntr:vCHE_Equipment_Number, bl:vCHB_Bl},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
        document.getElementById("chargeableAmount_"+Id).value= (data);
            }
        });
  }
</script>
}
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega los controladores necesarios y los modelos para reproducir tu escenario. Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, ya agregue lo que uso como controlador y como modelo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución y la publico por si de casualidad a alguien más le puede servir, únicamente metimos el valor que está trayendo el modelo con `@resumen2` dentro de la etiqueta output como cuando queremos imprimir un valor por pantalla y cerrando la etiqueta completamente con `</output>` en lugar del `/>` y que cuando se ejecute el evento javaScript cambie el valor predeterminado que trae del modelo por el nuevo que se ejecutó en el evento

```
    <td>
        <output id="chargeableAmount_@idFecha">
          @resumen2.calculoSP
        </output>
    </td>
```